how to use pydabs to create and configure workflows/pipelines?
At work we wanted to have more python configurability of our databricks workflows as well as be able to version control them via our Azure Repos. So we moved away from using the standard UI and adopted pyjaws which is a short term solution until Databricks releases a fully supported version.
Upon using pyjaws we found a number of limitations and now its time to move onto pydabs. The issue is, I have no clue how to switch over to pydabs.
I wanted to create a proof of concept first before moving our existing infrastructure over, and would be grateful for any pointers on the lines of code I will need and the sort of code blocks required.
https://pypi.org/project/databricks-pydabs/

This is a sample script I built long back. This uses an existing interactive cluster.
import os, time
from databricks.sdk import WorkspaceClient
from databricks.sdk.service.compute import (
    ClusterSpec,
    DataSecurityMode,
    Library,
    ResultType,
)
from databricks.sdk.service import jobs

w = WorkspaceClient()

notebook_path = f"/Users/{w.current_user.me().user_name}/workspace client"

cluster_id = (
    w.clusters.ensure_cluster_is_running("0828-152531-ze9eyjxc")
    or "0828-152531-ze9eyjxc"
)

print(cluster_id)

created_job = w.jobs.create(
    name=f"gc-sdk-test",
    tasks=[
        jobs.Task(
            description="GC SDK Demo",
            existing_cluster_id=cluster_id,
            notebook_task=jobs.NotebookTask(notebook_path=notebook_path),
            task_key="test",
            timeout_seconds=0,
        )
    ],
)

run_by_id = w.jobs.run_now(job_id=created_job.job_id).result()

print(run_by_id)

# cleanup
w.jobs.delete(job_id=created_job.job_id)


If you need to build a new cluster try this
c = w.clusters.create_and_wait(
    policy_id="your_job_policy_id",
    cluster_name="Small-Shared-UC-SDK",
    spark_version="14.1.x-scala2.12",
    node_type_id="i3.xlarge",
    data_security_mode=DataSecurityMode.USER_ISOLATION,
    spark_env_vars={"SOMEVAR": "Value1", "SOMEVAR2": "2"},
    spark_conf={
        "spark.name": "world",
        "spark.hadoop.datanucleus.autoCreateSchema": "true",
    },
)

and then read the
cluster_id = c.cluster_id

How do you specify a shared job cluster when building the new cluster, does the cluster name sort that?

The name is only for understanding.
Shared - All Purpose
"data_security_mode": "USER_ISOLATION",
"policy_id" : "your_policy_id" (Goto Compute > Policies > Shared Compute)
Single User Cluster
"data_security_mode": "SINGLE_USER"
"policy_id":"personal compute"
Job Cluster
"data_security_mode": "SINGLE_USER"
"policy_id": "policy_id_of_job_cluster"

If you want to know how to start using dabs. I would highly recommend going through this blog
Databricks Workflows with DABS

Use the Python SDK from Databricks. Databricks support it and will have updates when they launch a new feature.
https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/sdk-python.html
GitHub Repo with Examples.
https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sdk-py/tree/main/examples

are you able to direct me to a specific file whereby a workflow is created? Additionally, I've looked at the Databricks SDK link and found the cluster configuration section but can't see how they configure whether the cluster is a job cluster or an all purpose cluster? https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/sdk-python.html#create-a-cluster&language-venv
